# Geoserver Feature Versioning Support

Tags: postgis, geoserver, wfs, features, versioning

I am creating a map feature editor that supports versioning & rollback using Geoserver as the WFS.

From what I've read [online](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/developer/programming-guide/versioning/wfsv/samplecalls.html), it seems Geoserver supports feature versioning. My question is how do I implement versioning on Geoserver? Do I need to make any sort of modification on the data store for this to work or will the versioning be handled automatically by Geoserver?

Would be great if there was a tutorial on this.

Thanks.